# MOSS 2007 Permission error iterating users in group

Tags: permissions, groups, runwithelevatedprivileges

The following code, though run with elevated privildges, redirects to an access denied error page saying "You are currently signed in as:  (my non-admin account)." What am I doing wrong?

```
    SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
    {

        SPGroup group = SPContext.Current.Web.Groups["Group Name"];

        foreach (SPUser user in group.Users)
        {
           string email = CustomMethodGetsEmailFromProfile(user);
           SPUtility.SendEmail(...);
        }

     });
```

If I comment out the foreach loop, it works fine but defeats the purpose. Recall, I'm getting access denied. There's a few null checks that I didn't include as I'm writing this from memory.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2):

You can't/shouldn't use SPContext when elevating privileges, as the objects represented within it were created under a different (...in this case probably one with less privileges) security context.  Try something like this:

```
        SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
        {
            using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.ID))
            {
                using (SPWeb web = site.AllWebs[SPContext.Current.Web.ID])
                {
                     // then your code
                }
            }
        });
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: Rick, could you please mark it as answered so it's clear to others folks that this is an answered question.